# How to use Chrome debugger tool?

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, developer-tools

Hi I am trying to test the drawing speed(delay etc) on the canvas using the Chrome developer tools but I don't know which data shall I read.[image]

[image]

Comment: It will depend on what type of rendering you are doing. The chart view  is best suited for locating occasional calls that may be a poor performer. For seeing the performance of individual functions use the Tree (top down) view. You can see the total time of a function call and open it up all the way to individual canvas calls. It will also show you if the code is being optimised. Yellow triangle exclamation mark next to a function is bad unoptimized code. Or just use the performance API to do the timing yourself. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: i am testing the time taken for the object i draw on the canvas. should i look under painting or rendering?

Comment: Sorry my bad in the last comment, should have said Use the Profiler. The timeline will give you relative rendering times, and show GC both of which are relatively out of your control. If you go to the next Tab to the right "Profiles" and then record a CPU profile you will get a more manageable report with the ability to see times from the function entry point to individual call. If you are looking for optimisation this is the place to start. I personally have never found any good use for timeline apart from screen shots to locate a particular event for debugging reasons.